# How to close a dialog after the user selects an item from a spinner?

Tags: android, dialog, spinner, android-spinner, android-dialog

I have a dialog with a spinner. Currently, the dialog and the spinners works fine. However, the spinner doesn't close after I selected an item. I need it to be close and return to the activity after an item is selected. Thanks.

Here's the code for my dialog.

```
    String[] s = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };

        final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, s);

        final Spinner sp = new Spinner(getActivity());
        //sp.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        sp.setAdapter(adp);

        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Log.d("selectedItem:", selectedItem);

            } // to close the onItemSelected
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
            {

            }
        });

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setView(sp);
        builder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method on `Spinner` to close it,when spinner item is selected, and that will close your spinner, add to your `setOnItemSelectedListener`

```
sp.setSelection(int position)
```

and then just change your AlertDialog constructor a bit, put `alert.dismiss();` to dismiss the AlertDialog after user selects an item in your spinner

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(sp);
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Comment: When I selected an item, it doesn't close. How do I call the builder.dismiss() inside the spinner select method as the dialog hasn't been declare yet.

Comment: @Julia well, it should close itself, then maybe dismissing the dialog will be sufficient? You can dismiss the dialog onItemSelected as you first create a dialog then add spinner to it and only then the spinner is shown and user can actually click on an item and the method OnItemSelected in invoked so the dialog is already initialized as you see it. Just maybe you should change your dialog instantiation....I'll update the answer. Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    final Spinner sp = new Spinner(getActivity());
    sp.setAdapter(adp);

    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            String selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Log.d("selectedItem:", selectedItem);
            builder.dismiss();

        } // to close the onItemSelected
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
        {

        }
    });

    builder.setView(sp);
    builder.create().show();
```